# php session not working after publish on web hosting

Tags: php, session, session-variables

My website works fine on localhost, but once I deploy it to my hosting service, the session stops working.

```
<?php 

session_start();
session_save_path('log/session.txt');
ini_set('session.gc_probability', 1);
error_reporting(E_ALL ^ E_NOTICE);
date_default_timezone_set("Asia/Jakarta");
require_once 'jadwal/calendar/tc_calendar.php';

include "../metode/data.php"; 
include "../metode/jalan.php";
include "../metode/perintah.php";
include "../metode/gambar.php";

//session
$queryadmin = mysql_query("select * from root");
$dataadmin = mysql_fetch_row($queryadmin);
$id = $dataadmin[0];
$key1 = $dataadmin[1];

if (isset($_POST['admin'])) {
    $_SESSION['id'] = $_POST['x'];
    $_SESSION['key1'] = $_POST['xx'];
}
if (isset($_POST['root'])) {
    $_SESSION['user'] = $_POST['xxx'];
    $_SESSION['key2'] = $_POST['xxxx'];
}
if (isset($_POST['clear'])) {
    $_SESSION['id'] = "";
    $_SESSION['key1'] = "";
    $_SESSION['user'] = "";
    $_SESSION['key2'] = ""; 
}
if (isset($_POST['exit'])) {
    $_SESSION['id'] = "";
    $_SESSION['key1'] = "";
}

//access
if ($_SESSION['id'] == $id && $_SESSION['key1'] == $key1) {
    $user = $dataadmin[3];
    $key2 = $dataadmin[2];
    if ($_SESSION['user'] == $user && $_SESSION['key2'] == $key2) {
        mysql_query("insert into root history values('','".$_POST['day']."','".$_POST['time']."')");
    print "<br><br><br>";
    include_once "jembatan.php";
    } else {
        include "root.php";
    }
}
else {
    include "admin.php";
}

?>
```

If you need me to show any other files, just ask.

Answer (score 2):

Could be the way your hosting set up their PHP. Try printing phpinfo() on the host and check their settings.

To run the phpinfo function, just run a script that looks something like this:

```
<?php
    phpinfo();
?>
```

The output will include a huge list of settings, but you're looking for this section right her:

[image]

Note how my settings says **Session Support = enabled**. That's what indicates that my host (localhost, in my case) supports sessions.

Comment: Just add this to the top of your php file: <?php phpinfo(); ?> This will print all of the php settings your host has set, which will show you if they support session variables.

Comment: phpinfo() is a function. add it in a script and run it

Comment: how about this code "session_save_path('log/session.txt');". you have other way for code in have some function

Comment: for online website, how I call phpinfo() ?

Comment: 1) Create a new php file and name it test.php 2) open test.php in a text editor, and add the following to it: <?php phpinfo(); ?> 3) upload this file to your host 4) access the file from a browser - http://www.your-website.com/test.php

Answer (score 0):

Make sure there is no space or new line before onpenning the `<?php` tag, because you code here contains 3 spaces before it.

Comment: thanks, I have to try and still not working. give me another solved

Comment: if you don't, try moving this line 'error_reporting(E_ALL ^ E_NOTICE);' to the top of the script and see if you get any error after that ?

Comment: oke for move this code "E_ALL ^ E_NOTICE", but still not seen something like warning or error

Answer (score 0):

As late as this answer may be coming in, i recently ran into the same problem and after much trial and error. I found out the having the slightest HTML tag above your session could stop session from not registering.
So ensure the first thing you have at the top is

```html
<?php
session_start();
?>
```