# Session value lost after redirecting but it works on another hosting

Tags: web-hosting, php

Helo,

I'm having a problem with session variables. The session values lost after the page redirect to another.
I simplely used two pages for testing.

In the first page (test.php)-

```
<?php 
        session_start(); 
        $_SESSION['test'] = 'SS'; 
        header('location: test2.php'); 
?>
```

In the second page (test2.php)-

```
<?php
       session_start();
       echo $_SESSION['SS'];
?>
```

But there's no value on test2.php. Currently I'm testing on startlogic hosting and when I used the same pages 
on different hosting, it worked. Is that really hosting problem? PHP version or web server (aparche) issue?

Thank you,
Den

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On the test2.php you should have echo $_SESSION['test'] not $_SESSION['SS']. 'SS' was the value that you saved to the session variable and 'test' was the index.

Comment: Thank you Joonas. I've changed but still not showing the value.

Comment: Try printing php info with this <?php phpinfo(); ?> and check if sessions are enabled: Session Support = enabled http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14541771/php-session-not-working-after-publish-on-web-hosting